# How do I get GrindEQ (Latex plugin for Word) to work with Word in Wine?

Tags: linux, wine, latex

[GrindEQ](http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=latex2word) is a plugin for MS Word. It allows one to type LaTeX code into a Word document, then export that into Word's formatting (converts equations into Equation Editor equations, and takes care of labelling).

I want to get GrindEQ working in Linux under Wine. I have MS Word 2007 running in Wine, and I have installed GrindEQ into MS 2007 in Wine. However, GrindEQ does not work. I get an error "Can't find DLL entry point # in oleaut32.dll" I don't really know what to do! Any suggestions?

GrindEQ's website says people have gotten GrindEQ to work with Wine+Linux but they do not provide support to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WineHQ's appDB doesn't have any information regarding GrindHQ. On top of that, the developer's site mentions:

> Some of our customers report of successful launches under Linux+Wine,
>   but GrindEQ does not provide technical support for Linux.

In other words, it won't be easy and it will depend entirely on what version of Wine you're running, what DLLs you have and what version of Word/GrindHQ you have.

I would recommend emailing the GrindHQ developers and asking them who has reported being able to use it under wine. Then if you can get in contact with them, they could give you a rundown of how they did it on their system. Then you have to hpoe its a similar process on yours.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a Windows system running GrindHQ, check its `oleaut32.dll` version, and compare with the one in your wine system. If they're the same, `diff` the files to double-check.

If the files are different, try copying the one from the working windows install.

This may or may not work, and may or may not fix the issue, but the error sounds pretty much like an incompatible library, which is missing some function GrindEQ uses.

Even more important, if you suceed, tell Wine developers about the involved `oleaut32.dll` versions.

Maybe you're lucky and this is one of the only real issues you should get with Wine: non-implemented functions (what you sometimes get is programs that rely on undocumented behavior, sort of like [AARD code](http://enwp.org/AARD_code)) — I don't know whether the page is up-to-date, but a [WineAPI page on `oleaut32.dll`](http://source.winehq.org/WineAPI/oleaut32.html) lists the library as being 92% implemented (so, maybe GrindEQ uses something from the 8%).